# Call an input file doesn't work

Tags: file, r, input, bioconductor

I'm using Gviz library from bioconductor. I input a tab delimited file containing CNV position that I need to plot on my chromosome ideogram.

My input file is defined by dat and has 4 columns

- [1] chromosome
- [2] start
- [3] end
- [4] width (could '+' or '-' depending on the orientation of the Copy Number)

So I did that :

```
library(IRanges)
libraray(Gviz)
gen <- "mm9"
chr <- "chr1"

itrack <- IdeogramTrack(genome = gen, chromosome = chr)
gtrack <- GenomeAxisTrack()

dat <- read.delim("C:/R/1ips_chr1.txt", header = FALSE, sep ="\t")
s <- dat[2]
e <- dat[3]
l <- dat[4]
```

It shows an error message when I call the file dat :

```
atrack1 <- AnnotationTrack( start = s, width = l , chromosome = chr, genome = gen, name =  "Sample1")
Error : function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ".buildRange", for signature "NULL", "data.frame", "NULL", "data.frame"
```

Obviously the way I call a the inputed file (in dat) doesn't satisfy R .. Someone help me please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [reference manual](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/Gviz/man/Gviz.pdf) for the `Gviz` package (with which I am not familiar), the arguments `start` and `width` in the `AnnotationTrack` function need to be integer vectors. When you subset `dat` using the single square bracket `[`, the resulting object is a `data.frame` (see `` ?`[.data.frame` `` for more on this). Try instead

```
s <- dat[[2]]
e <- dat[[3]]
l <- dat[[4]]
```

to obtain integer vectors.